# Error while converting Bootstrap-Sass with gulp, but other sass files work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

Trying to convert bootstrap-sass to css using gulp. Here's my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

// Concatenate Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  var sassFiles = 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss'
  return sass(sassFiles, {style: 'compressed', emitCompileError: true})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'scss'));
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

This throws the following error:

```
[12:18:42] Starting 'sass'...
[12:18:45] What files should I watch? Did you mean something like:
    sass --watch input.sass:output.css
    sass --watch input-dir:output-dir
  Use --trace for backtrace.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Sass compilation failed. See console output for more information.
```

However, if I use my own sass files instead of bootstrap-sass it works fine and converts my sass to css as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: Is that the complete error?

Comment: Yes, that is the full error.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242546/sass-making-underscore-file-names-actually-create-css-files