# Sass 3.4.19 don't can use --watch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

My sass use

```
K:sass maizhikun$ sass  _bootstrap.scss ../CSS/Haplox.css
```

It is succeed.

But use

```
K:sass maizhikun$ sass --watch _bootstrap.scss:Haplox.css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
I, [2015-10-21T10:04:30.381624 #4494]  INFO -- : Celluloid 0.17.2 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242546/sass-making-underscore-file-names-actually-create-css-files

Comment: I removed the underline, also  wrong

Comment: You can't just remove the underscore when you call the watch command, you have to remove it from the file itself.

Comment: Yes,but my already  remove it from the file itself. eg:@import "bootstrap/tables";@import "bootstrap/forms";