# brunch sass dont' creat my css file

Tags: compilation, sass, brunch

I've add sass-brunch to my project, and when i start "brunch watch", brunch compile my JS fully but my scss is just "compiled in XXXms".

I don't see my app.min.css in public file, unlike JS which compiles perfectly.

My brunch-config.js :

```
module.exports = {
    paths: {
        watched: 'private'
    },
    files: {
        javascripts: {
            joinTo: 'js/app.min.js'
        },
        stylesheets: {
            joinTo: 'css/app.min.css'
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        sass: {
            options: {
                includePaths: [
                    'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
                    'node_modules/motion-ui/src'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242546/sass-making-underscore-file-names-actually-create-css-files

Comment: Can you maybe put up a small brunch project that demonstrates the issue on github and link it, so we could debug?

Comment: You can show this : https://github.com/LeG3nDz/www.modele-decoupe.lan/tree/brunch

Comment: Strange — I cloned it, `npm install`ed, and `brunch w` built both js *and* css.  Which brunch version are you on? I tried with 2.5.3. Can try with 2.5.3 and also try to remove `node_modules` and `npm install`, and see if it'll work?

Comment: I use 2.5.3 too. If i build, JS and CSS is creat. But with brunch watch, my CSS is empty :(

Comment: So `brunch b` is okay but `brunch w` is not? If so, that's really weird...